# URL with the current query

Tags: ajax, url, history, permalinks

I have an AJAX Web application where I want to have the URL to reflect what the current query is, in order to have a "permalink". For example a user enters "foobar" as a query in a search input, then `http://example/search/` in the URL bar becomes updated to `http://example/search/?foobar`.

When trying to implement this with index.html as:

```
<script>
query = "foobar";
window.location.search = query;
</script>
```

Firstly this strangely sends the browser in an endless loop. What am I missing?

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/kaihendry/Greptweet/issues/20#issuecomment-7875290

Comment: You haven't given us enough code to go on. Setting window.location.search will always reload the page, so if you set this on page load then it will loop.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `window.location` makes the browser reload that page.